# How to turn on capitals without pressing CAPS LOCK in vim insert mode

Tags: vim

I'm working with vim. I don't have remaped CAPS LOCK, nor I have activated it.
Yet, after I type `\ac{DC}` in insert mode, Vim turns on capitals. I have a hard time turning it off since I don't understand what's causing it (toggling CAPS LOCK won't work).

I'm baffled as to why, so I'd like to understand how can one turn on (and off) capital writing in insert mode without touching CAPS LOCK.
Thanks.

Comment: just typing `\ac{DC}` in insert mode I got literal `\ac{DC}` text... and capslock was not activated.

Comment: By default, Vim should not do this. There is probably a plugin or something else in your vimrc. See [How do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51) for some hints to find out *what exactly* is causing this. It's also possible that there is a program or setting on your system (or perhaps terminal?) which does this, so maybe try doing this in another program to see if it has the same effect...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Indeed the problem is not with vim, but with VMware Player. It has the same [bug](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004192) as VMware Fusion, when running on Unity mode.
BTW, to solve this on VMware Player all you have to do is switch context to the host, and then back again to the guest.